# Angular 2: Array Comma in URL using Router

Tags: javascript, angular

I have this A2 code:

```
this.router.navigate(['job-search'], {queryParams: {
            'fields': this.selectedFields
        }, replaceUrl: true});
```

`selectedFields` is an array of number:

```
selectedFields: number[] = [];
```

It produces this URL:

http://localhost:4200/job-search?fields=1%2C2

How can I modify this so that it yields:

http://localhost:4200/job-search?fields=1,2

I tried to `encodeURI(this.selectedFields.join())`

but it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

```
const fields = this.selectedFields.join();
this.router.navigate(['job-search'], {queryParams: {
    'fields': fields
}, replaceUrl: true});
```